# How to make sure that columns and rows will be printed as straigth lines using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

We can set this options to align the headers of the columns to 'center':

```
pd.set_option('display.colheader_justify', 'center')
```

How can we justify the data of the columns, when I print the data frame to a txt file I do not get the whole data in straight columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_string`:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fp:
    print(df.to_string(), file=fp)
```

Comment: It does not work. My data frame is 2000+ length